# Displaying the last 20 games played in a db

Tags: php, database

I have a db that displays a season's final scores in the NHL. This is the code i have but i only want to show the last 20 games of games played. Any help?

```
$query = 'SELECT id, date, concat(right(date, 4), mid(date, 4, 2), left(date, 2)) AS concat_date, home, away, homescore, awayscore FROM gamestats12 WHERE date <> \'date\' ORDER BY concat_date DESC LIMIT 20';
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT id, date, concat(right(date, 4), mid(date, 4, 2), left(date, 2)) AS concat_date, home, away, homescore, awayscore FROM gamestats12 WHERE date <> \'date\' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,20';
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the backslash (\) in `\'date\'`

And you can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) instead of 3 equalient substr's.